# Entity Framework call stored procedure and map to object

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have following data model in app

```
public class User
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Job AtJob {get;set;}
}

public class Job
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public sting Title {get; set;}
}
```

I call SQL Query with  following syntax

```
context.ExecuteStoreQuery<User>("SELECT Id, Name FROM dbo.[User]").ToList();
```

and it works. Problem is when I want return fields from Job and map them to object data model. For Example

```
context.ExecuteStoreQuery<User>
("SELECT U.Id, U.Name, J.Title 
  FROM dbo.[User] U 
  INNER JOIN dbo.[Job] J 
  ON U.JobId = J.JobId).ToList();
```

So, Is there any nice/simple way to map Job columns to User in object model?

Comment: Why don't you use `Linq to entities`?

Comment: I know that I can use Linq To entites, but I want implement some functionality via SQL Query.

Comment: you should save jobId in the user class and user db table, then you won't need any INNER JOIN in your queries

Answer (score 0):

why not use `Include()` and do this?:

```
var user = context.Users.Include(u => u.Job);
```